# Strange Objective-C/C `enum` behavior

Tags: objective-c, c

I have this strange issue:

When I create an `enum` like this:

```
typedef enum {    
    kParcelStatusInTransit,
    kParcelStatusArrived,
    kParcelStatusDelivered,
    kParcelStatusUnknown
} ParcelStatus;
```

I get an error: `expected identifier before numeric constant`

When I add even the smallest change to the members name, I get no error:

```
typedef enum {    
    kChangeParcelStatusInTransit,
    kChangeParcelStatusArrived,
    kChangeParcelStatusDelivered,
    kChangeParcelStatusUnknown
} ParcelStatus;
```

How is this possible? What numeric constant is the error talking about? It makes no sense to me...

Comment: Have you possibly `#define`d one of those identifiers somewhere? If so, the preprocessor would replace it with its value and the compiler would see that instead.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw you ARE right. It all makes sense now, I didn't declared the `enum` in other header, I used `#define` somewhere else. The syntax coloring in xCode didn't help so I got stuck. Thanks man!

Comment: could you post the answer so I can choose it?, maybe other people will have the same noobish problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the constants has been `#define`d in another file. Because of this, the preprocessor replaces the identifier in the `enum` with its value. The compiler then sees this constant value and complains, since it expected an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that one of the named constants you're trying to define is already defined in another header, possibly in one of Apple's frameworks. You'll simply need to pick a different name for your constants.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are defining the enum more than once, either literally or by including the file incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition I can say, compiling Your file with -E option and locating Your error code in a result file will help You to see what happened.
F.e.: cc -E myfile.c | grep -B 6 ParcelStatus